# Proving that $K_2$ is a theory with equality.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)" , page 98 , exercise 2.67 .

[image]

**My proof:**

To prove that it is a theory with equality using $2.25$ , it suffices to show that the following wfs are theorems of $K_2$

$(1)$ $x_1 = x_3 \to (x_1 = x_2 \to x_3 = x_2)$ 
$(2)$ $x_2 = x_3 \to (x_1 = x_2 \to x_1 = x_3)$ 
$(3)$ $x_1 = x_3 \to (x_1 <  x_2 \to x_3 < x_2)$ 
$(4)$ $x_2 = x_3 \to (x_1 < x_2 \to x_1 < x_3)$

$(1)$ 
$~~~~~x_1 = x_3 \to x_3 = x_1$ [axiom (b)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 = x_1 \to (x_1 = x_2 \to x_3 = x_2)$ [axiom (c)]
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3 \to (x_1 = x_2 \to x_3 = x_2)$

$(2)$ 
$~~~~~x_1 = x_2 \to (x_2 = x_3 \to x_1 = x_3)$ [axiom (c)]
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3 \to (x_1 = x_2  \to x_1 = x_3)$

$(3)$ 
$~~~~~x_1 = x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 < x_2$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 = x_2$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3 \to (x_3 = x_2 \to x_1 = x_2)$ [axiom (c)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_2$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_1 = x_2) \to \lnot(x_1 < x_2)$ [axiom (f)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\lnot(x_1 < x_2)$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2,x_3 = x_2\vdash(x_1 < x_2)\land \lnot(x_1 < x_2)$  
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2 \vdash \lnot(x_3 = x_2)$  [Contradiction]....$(i)$

Also,

$~~~~~x_1 = x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 < x_2$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 < x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_1 < x_2 \land x_2 < x_3) \to x_1 < x_3$ [axiom (e)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_1 < x_2 \land x_2 < x_3)$ [Conjunction introduction] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 < x_3$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3 \to \lnot(x_1 < x_3)$ [axiom (f)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\lnot(x_1 < x_3)$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2,x_2 < x_3\vdash(x_1 < x_3)\land \lnot(x_1 < x_3)$  
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash\lnot(x_2 < x_3)$  [Contradiction]....$(ii)$

$(i)$ $~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2 \vdash \lnot(x_3 = x_2)$ 
$(ii)$ $~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash\lnot(x_2 < x_3)$ 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash x_3 < x_2$ [axiom (g)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\vdash x_1 = x_3 \to (x_1 < x_2 \to x_3 < x_2)$ [Deduction]

$(4)$ 
$~~~~~x_2 = x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 < x_2$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_1 = x_3)\to (x_3 = x_1)$ [Axiom (b)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 = x_1$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3 \to (x_3 = x_1 \to x_2 = x_1)$ [axiom (c)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_1$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_2 = x_1)\to (x_1 = x_2)$ [Axiom (b)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_2$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_1 = x_2)\to \lnot(x_1 < x_2)$ [Axiom (f)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\lnot(x_1 < x_2)$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2,x_1 = x_3\vdash(x_1 < x_2) \land \lnot(x_1 < x_2)$  
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash \lnot(x_1 = x_3)$ [Contradiction] ....$(iii)$

Also,

$~~~~~x_2 = x_3$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 < x_2$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 < x_1$ [hyp] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_3 < x_1 \land x_1 < x_2) \to x_3 < x_2$ [axiom (e)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 < x_2$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_2 = x_3) \to (x_3 = x_2)$ [axiom (b)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_3 = x_2$ [MP] 
$\Rightarrow$$~(x_3 = x_2) \to \lnot(x_3 < x_2)$ [axiom (f)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\lnot(x_3 < x_2)$ [axiom (f)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2,x_3 < x_1\vdash(x_3 < x_2) \land \lnot(x_3 < x_2)$  
$\Rightarrow$$~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash\lnot(x_3 < x_1)$[Contradiction] ....$(iv)$

$(iii)$ $~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2 \vdash \lnot(x_1 = x_3)$ 
$(iv)$ $~x_2 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash\lnot(x_3 < x_1)$ 
$\Rightarrow$$~x_1 = x_3,x_1 < x_2\vdash x_1 < x_3$ [axiom (g)] 
$\Rightarrow$$~\vdash x_1 = x_3\to (x_1 < x_2 \to x_1 < x_3)$ [Deduction]  $\square$

> I am really skeptical of this proof (specially skeptical of part $(3)$ and $(4)$) because I did not use axiom (d) and axiom(h) even once. Maybe there is something crucial I am missing. Can someone tell me if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

$K_2$ is the theory of dense unbounded linear orders. (d) says that $K_2$ doesn't model something like $[0, 1],$ where you have a largest/smallest element. (h) says $K_2$ doesn't model something like $\mathbb{Z},$ where you have 'gaps' between elements. As such, you don't need them to prove $K_2$ is an order; they just say it is a nice order.

Comment: I dont know what "$K_2$ is an order" means.

Comment: I guess the question is not about the meaning of the theory $K_2$, but about formally proving (in the logical system defined in Mendelson's book, pp. 69-70)  that $K_2$ is a theory with equality (in the sense of Mendelson's book, p. 95), using Proposition 2.25 (p. 97).